# how to secure my input types from firebug and other debugging tool

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

```
<?php
    while($data['user'] as $row){
    <input type="check" value="<?php echo $row ?>" class="userid" />
    }
?>
<a href="" onlick="userdelete()"></a>
<script>    
    function userdelete(){    
        $('userid:checked').each(){
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({            
                //using codeignitor BASEURL and CONTROLLER 
                url: base_url+"index.php/admin/deleteuser",
                type: "POST",
                data: data,    
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {           
                    if (response) { 
                        $("#"+div).html(response);
                    }else { 
                        $("#"+div).html('ERROR');
                    }      
                }      
            });
        }
    }   
</script>
```

Suppose if i firebug it and change the value of check box  '1' in to '2'.. This ajax will delete another user instead to 1.

Please to protect my check boxes, input, select, and all other controller.

Comment: **Never** trust client input.

Comment: It isn't the client-side form you need to protect.  Your PHP which processes this form must check for appropriate permissions before performing the action.  This must _always_ be done.  If the logged-in user is not the owner of a  record, return an error message.

Comment: What @josh said. There is no way to protect this stuff. You need server-side protection, like an authentication system.

Comment: @Pekka what you mean by authentication system??

Comment: @zenolix That was Pekka's comment, not mine, but he's referring to the login system (login == authentication, more or less...).  You must verify that the logged-in user (stored in $_SESSION or whatever) is allowed to modify or delete the record.

Comment: @Michael. Well I've tried with Json but its become more complicated... Record which are coming from Database i convert them in to Json and validating through jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Encryption is the best solution for this**

Encryption is the conversion of data into a form, called a ciphertext, that cannot be easily understood by unauthorized people

Comment: Can you please give me any Example with code... I checked on PHP maunal 

string mcrypt_create_iv ( int $size [, int $source = MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM ] )

is this what you are talking about?

Thanks Anyway

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this with client-side operations. Firebug has completely control over the entire document in the borwser, and there is **NOTHING** you can do to prevent this.

If you don't want the user to fiddle with a value, then don't round-trip that value through the user's browser. Keep the ID of the record being modified in a server-side session variable, so that it's completely untouchable by the user.

Failing that, you would have to encrypt the value, so that instead of a nice clean `1`, they see some big ugly chunk of alpha-numeric garbage.

Answer (score 3):

The end user will **always** be able to manipulate the html and javascript that he/she receives and there's nothing you can do about it.

You will have to check the form submission data in your application to make sure that the user is following the rules. In this context I wouldn't even put the "id" in the form. With codeigniter, in your *deleteUser* function in your *Admin* controller you can retrieve the "id" of the currently logged in user using a similar line of code:

```
$this->session->userdata('user_id');
```

**Never** trust user submitted data.

Comment: basically: `<input type="text" name="recordID" value="<?php echo base64_encode($id) ?>" />`. But note that this is trivial OBFUSCATION, not encryption.

Comment: @MarcB. Its Good enough but how i convert it back to an ID or if I am using Ajax then??

Comment: use base64_decode when it's submitted back to the server. even though base64 is worse than useless for "encryption", you should never have the plaintext version of the id available on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent debugging it.

All the best you can do it to `minify or gzip` your javascript, which would make it hard to debug, but not impossible.

[This](https://developers.google.com/closure/) (and there could be many) is the link to minifying or gzipping your javascript

*But a recommendation is, use client side codes (javascrit/html/swf) for good user interactivity (not security). Use Server Side Code for your security!*

Comment: Minification does nothing to prevent an attacker from [fiddling](http://www.fiddler2.com) with values.

Comment: I said, it makes it difficult, not impossible. If your variables names are changed from username to a,b,c its surely bit difficult that what it was earlier :)

Comment: Not if you use a [debugging proxy](http://www.fiddler2.com/) to change the values in the HTTP request -- an attacker doesn't even have to *look* at the script.

Comment: @josh3736: I have updated the link, that gives link to gzip javascript, earlier link was mistakenly a simple minifying, not gzipping link, so it could have been a bit easier :)

Comment: @josh3736: even without using your debugging proxy link, a user can simply see the source code in browser, its the same thing what your debugging proxy can give you.

Comment: Gzipping does absolutely nothing since the browser automatically deflates all gzipped content.

Comment: And right, I'm just saying that minification will at best provide a false sense of security.

Comment: @josh3736: I have updated the link to correct tool this time, thats google closure tool. And again, I am not even saying that its providing any sort of security. I am just saying, that it will debug. And by gzipping I don't mean a server side gzip, but gzipping the file itself. for example: compare the jquery query minified version and jquery development version files. That's all what I meant. Its not impossible at all, but a bit difficult to debug, but again, I didn't say that it provides any kind of security!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot handle this. Never trust client input.